# Xamarin.iOS System.MissingMethodException: Method 'HttpResponseMessage.get_StatusCode'

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

On Visual Studio when a try to use HttpResponseMessage to get the response of a call to HttpClient.PostAsync i got this exception thrown :

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'HttpResponseMessage.get_StatusCode' not found.
```

The strange part of it is that i don't have this exception on Xamarin Studio.

The call is on a PCL linked to my ios application.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution after trying a lot of things.
Some times ago a fixed the CS0012 errors (these errors does not appear on Xamarin Studio) :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.   RiseUp.Framework.iO
```

by adding those missing references for Visual Studio.

The fix was to remove those references (system.runtime, system.Globalization etc...).

Now the workaround to remove those errors from the errors list is to show only the build error instead of the Build + Intellisense errors.
Those CS0012 errors appear to be a bug of Xamarin with Visual studio.